# Expect FloatTensors but got LongTensors in MNIST-like task

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am performing a MNIST-like task, the input is 10-class images, and the expected output is the predicted class of the images.

But now the `output` is like [-2.3274, -2.2723, ...], which the length is the batch_size. And the `target` is [4., 2., 2., 8., ...]

`Error message`: RuntimeError: expected object for scalar type Long but got scalar type float for argument #2 'target'

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    ...
    ...
    def forward(self, x):
        ...
        ...
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim = 1)


criterion = torch.nn.NLLLoss()
```

Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you got refers to the *second* (#2) argument of the loss: the `target`.
[`NLLLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/nn.html#torch.nn.NLLLoss) expects (for each element) to have a *float* vector of probabilities, and a single *long* (i.e., integer) target per element.
In your case, your "target" values are `[4., 2., 2., 8., ...]` which are of type *float*. you need to convert your target to long:

```
target = target.to(dtype=torch.long)
```